# C++, когда вызывается конструктор статичного объекта?

Tags: c++, static, конструктор

Подскажите, пожалуйста, когда для статичного объекта в `C++` вызывается конструктор?

```
static A a;

void func()
{
    static B b;
    // ...
}
```

Я предполагаю, что для локального объекта `b` конструктор будет вызываться при первом обращении к такому объекту.

Так же я предполагаю, что для глобального объекта `a` конструктор будет вызван в неопределенном порядке при запуске программы.

Верно ли мое представление?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для локального статического объекта `b` конструктор будет вызван тогда, когда управление в первый раз пройдет по вышеприведенному объявлению.

Для статического объекта `a`, определенного на уровне пространства имен, конструктор будет вызван *не позже*, чем произойдет первое обращение к какому-то объекту или функции, определенным в этой же единице трансляции. Такие объекты инициализируются в порядке сверху-вниз, как они определены в данной единице трансляции. Таким образом, порядок инициализации разных единиц трансляции не специфицируется, а вот порядок инициализации таких объектов внутри каждой единицы трансляции задан однозначно.

Answer (score 1):

Можете проверить сами. Достаточно написать программу типа такой:

```
struct A {  
    A(int n = 0) { 
        std::cout << "a";
        if (n)
            std::cout << n;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

A a;
void func()
{       
    A a2(2);
    const static A a3(3);
    static A a1(1);
    // ...
}
A a11(11);
void func10()
{
    static A a10(10);
    A a20(20);
    const static A a30(30); 
}
int main() {        
    func();
    func10();
    return 0;
}
```

Становится ясным, что первыми создаются глобальные обьекты, а другие(независимо от того статические или нет) создаются  по  той схеме, по какой они обьявлены.